# Open and close tabs in chrome with a timer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension that will take a list of newline-separated URLs and open them each in a new tab. I have all of that working perfectly, but also would like to have an option to close the tabs. The code below works, but it closes all the tabs at once after opening them all, and I would like it to be an iterative process instead (open 1, wait 1 second, close it, open 2, etc...) I don't understand why the code below is not behaving that way already and would appreciate some explanation/tips/solution.

js:

```
document.getElementById('openButton').onclick = openLinks;

function openLinks()
{
    var links = document.getElementById('linkInput').value;
    var arr = links.split('\n')
    if (document.getElementById("close").checked)
    {
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: arr[i], active:false}, function(tab)
                           {
                             setTimeout(function()
                                        {
                                          chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
                                        }, 1000);
                           });
        sleep();
      }
    }
    else
    {
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: arr[i], active:false});
        sleep()
      }
    }
}

function sleep() {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > 1000){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h2 align="center">Link Opener</h2>
  <textarea id="linkInput" rows="10" cols="60">Paste Links Here</textarea>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="close" id="close">Autoclose tabs
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" id="openButton">Open</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<script src="background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.tabs.create()` is an asynchronous function. This means that your whole loop completes before any of the tabs is created and the callbacks are called.

1. You slowly, with a hugely inefficient loop put tab creations in the queue.
2. Your function exits.
3. The queue is processed (very quickly), each instance adding the timeout to the queue (at approximately the same time).
4. In a second, all tabs are closed, since the timeouts all fire at approximately the same time.

---

Do NOT use this `sleep()` function. It does not allow other queued actions to execute while waiting, burns the CPU needlessly, and it does not guarantee that it will wait a second (`1e7` iterations can finish much quicker, potentially). You should set timeouts instead. This way, you can build the asynchronous queue all at once and then just let the browser sort out the delays.

```
function openTab(url, autoclose){
  return function(){ // The closure is needed to bind arr[i]
    chrome.tabs.create({url: url, active:false}, function(tab){
      if(autoclose) {
        setTimeout( function() {
          chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
  }
}

  var autoclose = document.getElementById("close").checked;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    setTimeout( openTab(arr[i], autoclose), 1000*i);
  }
```

This will schedule the tabs at once, but they will open at 1-second intervals. If `autoclose` is true, then each tab will also close itself after a second.

Comment: Did a bit of tweaking to fit other features I added since posting the question, but worked like a charm. Thank you, and an extra thank you for the explanation!